# Google Maps React not loading

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

I am showing a basic example of Google Maps React with a valid key but isntead of showing me the map it shows me a text saying "Loading map..."

```
import {GoogleApiWrapper, Map, MapProps} from 'google-maps-react';
import * as React from 'react'

export class MapContainer extends React.Component<MapProps> {

public render() {
  return (
    <Map 
        google={this.props.google} 
        centerAroundCurrentLocation={true}
        zoom={20}
    />
  );
 }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: (API_KEY)
})(MapContainer)
```

There is no error in console log and anything.

Comment: How do you include your `MapContainer` component where you use it? It should be `import MapContainer from './pathToContainer/MapContainer'`, instead of `import { MapContainer } from  './pathToContainer/MapContainer'`. Your goal is to use the default exported Container, because of the `GoogleApiWrapper` HOC.

Comment: @JordanEnev i change what you said and now the message dissapear. It seems that the map is loadod but the page it still in blank

Comment: Did you provide `const style = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%'
}` ?

Comment: You can check my complete answer. There you can find a link to a working example. About the blank page, you can try to add a style to the wrapper's map div and the map itself. Also you can try skipping `centerAroundCurrentLocation={true}`, just for making sure that the flag doesn't cause the issue.

Answer (score 8):

First of all please make sure on the places you're including the MapContainer you're using the default export as follows:

`import MapContainer from './pathToContainer/MapContainer'`

Otherwise importing it via named export `{ MapContainer }` you will skip `GoogleApiWrapper` HOC.

---

Also you may need to provide the width and height maps properties as follows:

```
<Map 
  style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
  google={this.props.google} 
  centerAroundCurrentLocation={true}
  zoom={20}
/>
```

Or you may need to style the map's wrapper div:

```
<div
  style={{
    position: "relative",
    height: "calc(100vh - 20px)"
  }}
>
  <Map 
    google={this.props.google} 
    centerAroundCurrentLocation={true}
    zoom={20}
  />
</div>
```

Here's a [complete working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rzwrk2854), taken from the docs.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me !!

Comment: Glad to hear it :) If it's useful and resolved your case - you can accept it. Thanks :)